# How to add Saripaar Validator in code and not as attribute?

Tags: android, validation, saripaar

As explained on [official GitHub page](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar#quick-start) adding validators through attributes is easy as:

```
@NotEmpty
@Email
private EditText email;
```

Now that EditText will be validated that it's not empty and that it contains email. But, now, how can I can add those two same conditions from within the code? Looking through code it seems there is this method:

```
public <VIEW extends View> void put(final VIEW view, final QuickRule<VIEW>... quickRules)
```

And I tried using it like:

```
mValidator.put(txtDestinationAddr, new NotEmptyRule(), new EmailRule());
```

But seems that constructors for all rules are protected and can't be used this way.